# Enterprise Architect + SVN: package lock visibility

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

Is there any way to have visibility in EA on packages if related file is locked in SVN or not? I'm using EA v12 + TortoiseSVN v1.7.11.

The only way I found is to select a package context menu > 'Package Control' > 'File properties…' > 'Lock Owner' field.

It's rather tedious and I'd like to have some special package icon in Project Browser tree or at least a note in mouse-over tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to write an add-in or send a [feature request](http://www.sparxsystems.com/support/feature_request.html) to Sparx Systems and wait.

Writing an add-in is not as scary as it sounds. I've posted some articles about that on my website: http://bellekens.com/writing-ea-add-ins/